# Is xposed safe for my phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, unbricking, xposed-framework, micromax

I've a Micromax bolt A064 running on 4.4.2 kitkat. After rooting the device, I somewhere read that xposed can give my phone more tweaks than ever I can. So, I started reading about xposed. Some users said that it was safe and they were enjoying whereas some user's phone was soft-bricked or bootloooped. I certainly come to know that it can harm my device also. But I want something new in my phone. So, the best idea that my brain gives to me is to ask from the experts and intelligents  here. I'm now having stock rom but rooted with kinguser. I replaced kinguser with Supersu and now using it. You can check the details of my phone on manufacturer website. Alternatively, I'm attaching a screenshot of my setting's about phone. 
Again highlighting question-

> **Is xposed safe for my micromax bolt a064**

And, if it is safe, could you please list some useful modules that is supported i.e safe?

Thank you for your attention. If any details is needed, comment it and I'll surely give it. And please help.

----------------------Thank you-----------------

[image: Here is the screenshot.]

Answer (score 3):

Nobody will give you any guarantee – but a few hints we can give. I'm using *Xposed* on multiple devices, and encountered no issues. So here a few points to consider:

- before installing *Xposed,* make a full backup (best a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup)) – so you always can revert in case things go weird.
- make sure your device has a [custom recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) (in fact, that's a pre-condition for the Nandroid backup), and you can use it. Follow the link to learn about it in case you're not yet familiar with this.
- when you install *Xposed* using the *Xposed Installer*, it will create a "recovery package" – so if your device/ROM has issues with *Xposed* and doesn't boot up anymore, you should be able to simply boot into recovery, and install that package – which would revert the *Xposed* installation and restore your device to its previous state.
- not a bad idea to repeat step-1 before installing a new module, but that's not a strict requirement; removing *Xposed* as described in the step before should "deactivate" a misbehaving module along the lines – and if not, restoring the Nandroid backup for sure does.

> And, if it is safe, could you please list some useful modules that is supported i.e safe?

That's a) too broad, and b) off-topic here. But be welcome to grab an idea from my [Xposed Framework Resource Collection](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_xposed) (and the other lists on that site: Xposed modules are usually part of the corresponding "topic list", so the "resource collection" doesn't hold them all). Which ones to use completely depends on your needs :)

Comment: "*it will create a "recovery package"*" -- where does it create that?

Comment: @Firelord it will tell you :) Usually on your SD card, below `Android/data/*`.

Comment: Fine.... Just tried to install it and got on bootloop........ But I've fixed it. Anyway, thanks for replying.

Comment: Yeah, that's one thing that "recovery package" is for: boot to recovery and restore. I vaguely remember it said somewhere that boot-loops might happen "in rare cases"; I've never encountered any in this context. I don't know how far the Micromax is from AOSP (i.e. how heavy its ROM is modiefied), which might be a reason for this: the more AOSP-like the ROM, the more unlikely the boot-loop case.